# How can I pass a selected object from an array (firestore) to another class in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question about passing specific Objects from an array to another class in react native. If I press the button, all objects go to another class instead of the one I need, but I want the one which I pressed. Do I have to create a function for the selected object/ key or is it enough if I change something in the onPress={} method?

I need to change something here -> TouchableOpacity   onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('detail', item,{})}>  Item must be the document (firestore) with all the information I have, but how can I pass the object from the array only?

Here are also some pictures for a better understanding, thank you in advance

```
export default class foods extends Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        posts:[],
      }
    }
     
    componentDidMount() {
      StatusBar.setHidden(true)

      this.subscriber = database.collection('users').onSnapshot(docs => {
        let posts = []
        docs.forEach(document => {
          posts.push({
            id: document.id,
            ...document.data(),
          })
        })
        this.setState({posts})
        console.log(posts)
      })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ScrollView> 
          <View style={styles.container}> 
            {  
              this.state.posts.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <View >
                    {
                      Object.keys(item.post).map((key) => {
                        return (                         
                          <View style={styles.card}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('detail', item, {})}>  
                              <Text>{item.firstName} {item.lastName}</Text>
                              <Image style={styles.cardImage} source={{ uri: item.post[key].image }} />
                              <Text>{item.post[key].essenname}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                          </View>
                        )
                      })
                    }
                  </View>
                )
              })
            }      
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
}

    export default class detail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      post: [this.props.route.params]
    }
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true)
    console.log('Array : ', this.state.post)
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          {this.state.post.map((item) => {
          return (
              Object.keys(item.post).map((key) => {
                return (
                  <View style={styles.card}>
                   
                    <Image style={styles.cardImage} source={{ uri: item.post[key].image }} />
                    <Text>{item.post[key].essenname}</Text>
                  </View>
                )
              })
            )

          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

    );
  }
}


  


I want to pass either Post[0] or Post[1] but not both:
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3recX.png)

This is my output, which is the same output after navigating the item to the detail screen:
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMqrd.png)

Detail screen on the right:
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIX0V.png)

The document with the array 'post':
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO1uQ.png)
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to navigate the selected/pressed object from the array 'post' to the detail screen. I dont want to pass all objects from the array to the detail screen, only the one I pressed, sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `Object.keys` to loop trought your posts, just use `item.post`.
In your navigation params, just use a spred operator for the root key and pass the post selected: `this.props.navigation.navigate('detail', {posts: {...this.state.posts, post: [p]}})`.
In your detail component state your are missing to access the params, it should be:

```
this.state={
 post:[this.props.route.params.posts]
}
```

and replace `Object.keys` with `item.post`

Comment: I have access to the Item in the next screen, but the Item has all datas (the array with the 2 objects Post[0] and Post[1] too.) But I want  the object which has been pressed, either post [0] or post[1]. this image shows my problem -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/3recX.png. I bring Post[1] to the detail screen too, but I want Post[0] only. I was thinking to replace item with  item.post[key] like here ->   onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('detail', item.post[key])}>  But what I get is this ->  undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(item.post)'). Im sorry for my explanation

Comment: You are right, should be item[post].key. You should share  also the detail page code.

Comment: I added item[post].key, I got this report -> can't find variable post. I added the detail class  now, you can check it. Thank you for your support by the way

Comment: there is no need to use Object.keys(item.post) in details component as you have a different data model. If you define your state with this.state = {
      post: this.props.route.params.item
    }
without the brakets, then you can access your post data with this.state.post.essenname ecc. If you need more help try to create a snack (https://snack.expo.io/) and I'll help you there

Comment: I changed everything you said and postet it right here https://snack.expo.io/hlr-Xwt7h            I get the error can't find variable post, are you sure that  onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('detail', item.post[key])}> is right? Thanks

Comment: your snack is not working. Try to add a fake dataset such the one you posted on the image, make it working and I'll help you

Comment: Or at least give me your state object that you have in this.state.posts

Comment: Here a working example of your snack: https://snack.expo.io/@nordup/post-array